# CSS3 responsive background image gets blurry

Tags: html, css

I am using png image as background of the td inside a table. I am using "background-size: cover" to make it responsive. But the background image gets blurry on smaller windows. Its fine on full size. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-image: url(image.png)">
      <div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


css:
table td{
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 96px;
}
```

Comment: You could use a media query to change the background-size from cover to not cover?

Comment: did you try, background-size:contain;

Answer (score 4):

No.

The PNG image is pixel-based. Scaling it makes it blurry, whatever you do. Perhaps you're watching the image on a smartphone with high resolution display, and it will be even worse.

The only real solution for this is using vector graphics, like SVG images.

Comment: I also thought of using vector images. But there are quite lot of images. Anyway, guess there are no other options.. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: Just trying to save you time ;-) Anyway, you could make the source image a bit fuzzy itself or obscure it a bit/put a gradient over it to make it less obvious. Should not be too big a problem since background images are in the 'background' after all...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a responsive way, you may consider using a smaller image on a smaller screens, with media queries -

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="background-one">
      <div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table td {
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 96px;
}

.background-one {
    background-image: url('image-1.png');
}

@media all and (max-width: 420px) {
    .background-one {
        background-image: url('image-1-small.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the bakcground-size roule, the proglem is the background-position:center. Try to change the image-rendering css roule.

Answer (score -1):

May be set table width?

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```